# How do I provide input to a background program created by execl?

Tags: c, pipe, fork, execl

I am writing a C program on Linux. At the same time I have an executable file A. I need to call A in the C program I am writing. but to run A I need to press any key, and I need to pass a key to the program I am writing after it calls A.

The approximate logic of A is as follows:

```
// read some config files

fprintf(stderr, "\n---------Hit Any Key To Start");
getc(stdin);

// the rest of the business
```

I refer to some information on the Internet and write the code as follows:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

int fd[2];
int read_end = 0;
int write_end = 1;

if(-1 == pipe(fd)) {
    // error warning
}
if(-1 == pid) {
    // error warning
}else if (0 == pid) {
    close(fd[write_end]);
    dup2(fd[read_end], STDIN_FILENO);

    // I am using execl to execute A. 
    // According to the logs, A executes to where it is waiting for input.
    execl(A ...)
}else {
    close(fd[read_end]);
    char key = 'y';

    // The two inputs are just me worrying that A didn't get the message so I input it a few more 
    // times, but it doesn't work
    write(fd[write_end], &key, sizeof(key));
    sleep(10);
    write(fd[write_end], &key, sizeof(key));

    // I need to terminate A after it executes for a while, so I wrote this code.
    sleep(75);
    kill(pid, SIGTERM);

    // Other things
    // ...
}
```

What I expect to happen is that I am starting my program with a bash script, then my program calls A and lets A run normally for a while and then exits.

I am not a native English speaker, so please let me know if my wording is wrong.

Comment: Can you not simply get the key before you execute the program and include the key in your `execl()` argument list? See [man 3 exec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin     I'm afraid not. In the best case, I cannot change the execution logic of A. If I pass new parameters, it means I need to change the source code of A program.

Comment: My thought being that `execl ("/path/to/A", ptr_to_key, (char*)NULL)` would call `A` with `ptr_to_key` as the argument for `A`. There is no need to change `A`, but if you can know `key` before you call `A`, you can just pass `key` (as a nul-terminated string) as the argument for `A` in the child-process without ever having to pipe between parent and child process.

Comment: Or are you saying `A` reads from `stdin` and doesn't take a program argument? In that case, then yes, you need to pipe input to `A` as you are attempting.

Comment: Send a newline with the key. Most of the programs want an enter. Are you writing program `yes`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for your guidance. In detail A accepts parameters, I have filled them in execl and ended with NULL. What is happening now is that after A accepts the parameters the run needs to start by pressing any key as `getc(stdin);` .The key here is just any trigger button. This is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have tried `key = '\n'` , but it doesn't seem to work. I am indeed writing a program to use the executable A in the processing flow, but I can't change A...

Comment: `it doesn't seem to worl` "Doesn't work" is not an error description. What _happens_? What is the return value of `write()`? What does executable `A` do? How does it work? How to reproduce locally? Are you writing program `yes`, see `man yes`? Send a newline with the key. Consider creating a full [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pid_t pid = fork();

int fd[2];
int read_end = 0;
int write_end = 1;

if(-1 == pipe(fd)) {
```

You created the pipe after fork, so the pipe is local to the process. Create it before forking, so it is shared.

Overall, your whole program looks like `timeout 75 bash -c 'yes | "$@"' -- A` and doesn't look like requires a separate compiled C code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I got it running using your alternative method. The previous reply to you was not standardized and did not contain enough information. I apologize for that. I'll try to find more detailed error messages.